# Angular routing html5mode ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, url-routing, angular-routing

I have an angularjs app which based on ASP.NET project, it uses html5mode and works perfectly fine unless I want pass route parameter(s).

Angular routing:

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

 $routeProvider.when('/accounts', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/accounts.html',
            controller: 'accountsCtrl',
            title: 'Accounts',
            resolve: {
                accounts: function (accountData) {
                    return accountData.getAll();
                }
            }
        });

        $routeProvider.when('/account/:accId', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/editAccount.html',
            controller: 'editAccountCtrl',
            title: 'Account',
            resolve: {
                account: function ($route, accountData) {
                    return accountData.get($route.current.pathParams.accId);
                }
            }
        });
```

web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^index\.html" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="None" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />

        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Rout localhost:3849/accounts - works, but localhost:3849/account/1 breaks the system, it looks like it fail to load *.js libraries or any other resources.

console shows

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

for every single library. What wrong?
Thanks

**UPDATE**
The problem was how scripts referenced in the index.html.
Original was:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Has to be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
```

so when I asked server to go to localhost:3849/account/1 it started to look all files at localhost:3849/account, didn't find them and returned index.html.
 The same problem in routing, instead of

```
templateUrl: 'templates/editAccount.html',
```

must be:

```
templateUrl: '/templates/editAccount.html',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead (you may need to tweak the path to index.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>

  <system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="../index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>

</system.webServer>


</configuration>
```

Comment: Hmm.  That configuration should work.  I'd recommend you use Fiddler to inspect the failed requests.  It's likely that the routing rules are returning the default file (html) instead of your resources.

Comment: Looking more closely, how are your URLs referenced?  The relative path would change and cause your .js files to 404/redirect to index.html if they were not properly rooted.

Comment: Thanks, finally I figured out the problem - updated the question. Silly me =(